# [template-matching], make [matchtemplate] a synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

- [template-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-matching), 344 questions, 19 watchers
- [matchtemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matchtemplate), 58 questions, 1 watcher (me)

I've noticed the existence of both these tags, which are essentially for the same thing. Any slight nuances in meaning are covered by tagging the specific library.

I can retag all of `matchtemplate` to be `template-matching`. Afterwards I'd like to see that turned into a synonym.

Is this the right way to go about this?